# Postgres looped table (start sequence from 1 and rewrite old rows)

Tags: postgresql

I want table to contain logs and be looped, so when it came to last key in sequence it will start over from one and will rewrite old logs.

I can do it if i mark sequence  as cycle and do requests like that:

```
INSERT INTO logs (initiator_id, target_id, action, message) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET target_id=$2, initiator_id=$1, action=$3, message=$4;
```

What i don't like, is that i need to repeat same iserts if there is conflict (line 2)

What i'am curios about, is it a good way to do, or there is other more practical ways for tables that you need clear lets say every 3 mounts?

Or maybe there is a way to generate unique id without using sequences?

Answer (score 0):

For now i decided to make 2 colums primary key (date, initiator_id) as log is always 1 action at a time.